# Find index of list using binary recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

So, ive been instructed to create a function with 2 parameters, a list and a number, that uses a binary recursive search to see if a number is in a list. If the number is in the list i'm to return its index and if its not I am to return -1. So far i have

```
def findIndex(alist,num):
     print(alist)
     if len(alist) % 2 == 0:
          mid = int((len(alist)/2)-1)
     else:
          mid = ((len(alist)//2))

     if alist[mid] == num:
          print(mid)
     elif alist[mid] > num:
          findIndex(alist[0:mid],num)
     elif alist[mid] < num:
          findIndex(alist[mid+1:],num)
```

I know how a binary search works. Do to the middle, if its not the number you're searching for compare that number to the number you're searching for. If its greater than the number youre searching for, search the front half of the list. If its lesser, search the back half of the list again. The problem is my code only works in the case that the number I'm searching for is less than the middle number in every case.

Answer (score 1):

**ANALYSIS**

There are several problems with the logic.

1. The deleted post nailed your most glaring problem: your search works only when the search target appears in the middle of a series of left-only divisions.  Otherwise, you print 0, the index when the list gets down to a single item.
2. If the target is not in the list, your program crashes on index out of range, when you try to find the midpoint of an empty list.
3. You never return anything.  Printing a result is not the same as returning a value.

**SOLUTION**

There are two straightforward ways to handle this.  The first is to use **findIndex** as a wrapper function, and write the function you want to be called by that.  For instance:

```
def findIndex(alist,num):
    return binaryFind(alist, 0, len(alist), num)

def binaryFind(alist, left, right, target):
    # Here, you write a typical binary search function
    #   with left & right limits.
```

The second is to return the index you find, but adjust it for all of the times you cut off the left half of the list.  Each level of call has to add that adjustment to the return value, passing the sum back to the previous level.  The simple case looks like this, where you're recurring on the right half of the list:

```
    elif alist[mid] < num:
        return (mid+1) + findIndex(alist[mid+1:], num)
```

Does that get you moving toward a useful solution?